# Android: Get Resource ID of custom xml class object by name

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I have a custom folder, file and custom XML resource class in my "res" folder.

I create some custom objects, which I call:

```
<area id="@+id/someId" name="Some Name" />
```

I can access them statically by R.id.someId.

However, I need to get the resource id at runtime and I need to do that by the "name". In other words, I display that "Some Name" in the list and I need to get the id of  knowing that the user selected "Some Name" from the ListView. (I am **NOT** looking for the id of the ListItem, I actually want to search my resources and get the id of the area xml object)

For example:

I would like to do something of the following:

```
int id = getIdFromResourceName("Some Name");
```

Is this possible?

I have tried using:

```
int i = this.getResources().getIdentifier("Some Name", "area", this.getPackageName());
```

...but that did not seem to work. I always get 0.

**EDIT**

As suggested below by Geobits, is there a way to load all of the resources from a res file and save them in an array/map, such as `Map<id,name>` so I can search them later?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need. But here is my solution proposal. This is how I would do it, if your resource was a drawable:

```
    public int findResourceIdByName(String name) {
        Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();  // get all drawables
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {        // loop through all drawable resources in R.drawable
                int curResId = fields[i].getInt(R.drawable.class); // Returns the value of the field in the specified object as an int.
                                                                  //This reproduces the effect of object.fieldName

                Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon); // get the Drawable object
                if(drawable.getName().equals(name)) {   //getName() is NOT possible for drawable, this is just an example
                    return curResId;                    // return the corresponding resourceId
                                                        // or you could return the drawable object instead, 
                                                        // depending on what you need.
                }
            }

            return -1; // no ResourceId found for this name

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is using Reflection, so it won't be the most efficient approach. If you call this method frequently, you might need to cache the result of

```
Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
```

at least.

Comment: I eventually followed this line of thought. I loaded all of the names from my XML document and matched them up with the ID using a modification of this method. This code gives me the id name and id int, loading from xml i have area name and area id name, this way I can match up int id with area name. _name <-> id_name <->id_name<->int_id_

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful to you, even though it was written for a drawable resource. I just wasn't sure what kind of custom resource I had to use, which is why I picked drawable instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
int i = this.getResources().getIdentifier("someId", "id", this.getPackageName());
```

The `defType` it wants is what form of identifier it is. Since it's `R.id.someId`, you want `id`. If it were `R.drawable.someDrawable`, you'd use `drawable`.

Comment: I tried:

`int itemId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("Some Name", "id", this.getPackageName());` And I still get itemId == 0.

Comment: Don't use `Some Name`, use `someId`.

Comment: But at that point, I only know the user clicked on "Some Name", I want to find the id associated with "Some Name".

Comment: Ok, I see. You threw me off in your OP with the code using `someId`. I think you may need to keep a list of your custom objects and search them by name manually in code.

Comment: Hmm, sorry. I was hoping there would be an easier way to do this. Parse it out of xml?

Comment: Possible, sure. Wouldn't it just be easier to keep a list of what id belongs to what name, though?

Comment: How would I go about storing it in an array/map? Can I load all resources from my custom res/areas/areas.xml file and store it in a Map<id, name> so I can search it later?

Comment: Hmm, well if you're already loading them all for something else(initializing,etc) at runtime, I'd do it then. If not, parsing might be the better answer after all. `Resources#getXML` would probably be the cleanest.

Comment: I am not sure how I would get the compiled int id out of it. Could you please provide a sample?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to get the compiled id. You'd have to match the named id, and then use `getIdentifier`. Maybe there's a better way of going about it, though. Is there a reason you *have* to search it by the name attribute?

Comment: I don't know how to do it differently. I have array of strings which populate the user shown list and "areas" list of objects, and the way my code is, I need to get the id for the object with the specified "name" to continue with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier("name", "id", getPackageName());
```

to get the ID of the resource.